# How much are odd lot fees for NYSE stocks

Tags: stocks, fees

I can't find a listing for odd lot fees ( less than 100 shares of common stock). They used to be 1/4 or 1/2 point depending on the stock price . On my Vanguard transactions I do not see any separated fee listings. There must be many transactions with odd lots today as so many popular stocks have prices very high for a retail ( aka , little) investor to buy 100 shares.

Comment: I had that same question a while back, and IIRC the answer was that odd lot fees are as obsolete -- but for a different reason, and happened later -- as fractional pricing.  Computers just made it... unnecessary.

Comment: Vanguard joined the list of no commission brokers in January.

Comment: The old odd lot fee was in addition to the standard commission ;  as if it were paid to the specialist of a stock rather than the broker.

Comment: I get odd lot fills all the time  in my trading account.  There is no odd lot fee nor has there been one for the past 20 years.  If you paid an odd lot fee to Vanguard prior to their eliminating commission charges then that was a fee specific to Vanguard's policy.

Comment: I must be getting old. I thought it may have been Vanguard policy to not charge them.